If X and Y are unbounded rvs that have the same moment generating function do they have the same distribution
$X$ and $Y$ are unbounded random variables, if $X^n$ and $Y^n$ are integrable for all n, and $E(X^n) = E(Y^n)$ for all $n\ge0$ must $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution?
My intuition says no. I’ve proved they have the same moment generating function, but that only implies they have the same distribution if it’s finite. I’ve seen in other similar questions that the log-normal distribution might provide a counter example.
I was hoping to make use of a previous part of the question where I showed that if A is the standard normal distribution & $P(B=k)=\lambda e^\frac{-k²}{2}$ for $k\in \mathbb{Z}$ then $E(e^{jA})=E(e^{jB})$ (although this apparently doesn’t imply they have the same generating function, and I think that’s related to B being discrete but I’m not sure).
Any advice would be appreciated.

Stieltjes observes that for all $n$ we have $$\int_0^{\infty}e^{-x^{1/4}}\sin (x^{1/4}) x^ndx=0.$$ Now $\frac{1}{18}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-x^{1/4}}dx=1.$ Then $$\frac{1}{18}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-x^{1/4}}(1+c\sin (x^{1/4}) x^n)dx=m_n$$ does not depend on $c\in [-1,1].$
